# How to write ${(0.\bar 1)_{12}}$ as a rational number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In decimal, you multiply by 10 and subtract off the the original to cancel out the fractional part etc. In this case you would have to multiply by 12 right? Then I need to write 11 in base 12 which I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\left(\dfrac1{12}\right)^r=\dfrac{\dfrac1{12}}{1-\dfrac1{12}}=\dfrac1{11}$$

More generally in base $b,$

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\left(\dfrac1b\right)^r=\dfrac{\dfrac1b}{1-\dfrac1b}=\dfrac1{b-1}$$

Comment: That is a great answer, thanks. Do you know how to write 11 in base 12?

Comment: @SumMathGuy, Welcome. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duodecimal#Places

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
In base 10, you write 1/9, which is 1/(base-1).
In base 12, try getting something similar.